# how do I make all my paragraphs of list, align the same

Tags: html, css, list, margin, vertical-alignment

I have two paragraphs with ordered lists, but on my website, the paragraphs are not on the same line going vertically. Its a very slight difference but I need to fix it. I've tried changing the margins in the CSS but both of the paragraphs move at the same time. The second paragraph is more to the right than the first paragraph, I need it to align with the first paragraph.

here is the code

```
    <div id="content">
          <div class="content_item">
            
            <br />
<h1> Conference/Workshop Publications </h1>
<ol>

<br /><li>Deb, D., Jones, E., "University-wide Adoption of Data Science", 51th ACM SIGCSE Conference, February 2020.<a href="https://doi.org/10.1145/3328778.3372657">
Link</a></li>


<br /><li>Deb, D., Smith, R. M., and Fuad, M, "Infusing Data Science Across Disciplines", In Proceedings of the 2019 ACM Conference on Innovation and Technology in Computer Science Education (ITiCSE), July 2019.<a href="https://doi.org/10.1145/3304221.3325579">
Link</a></li>

<br /><li>Deb, D., Fuad, M., Irwin, K., "A Module-based Approach to Teaching Big data and Cloud Computing Topics at CS Undergraduate Level", In the Proceedings of the SIGCSE '19: the 50th ACM Technical Symposium on Computer Science Education, February, 2019.<a href="https://doi.org/10.1145/3287324.3287494">
Link</a></li>

<br /><li>Deb, D., Cousins, S., Fuad, M., "Teaching Big Data and Cloud Computing: A Modular Approach", In the Proceedings of the 32nd IEEE International Parallel and Distributed Processing Symposium Workshops (IPDPSW), May, 2018.<a href="https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8425437">
Link</a></li>

<br /><li>Deb, D., "On the Integration of Big Data and Cloud Computing Topics”, 48th ACM SIGCSE, March 2017.<a href="https://doi.org/10.1145/3017680.3022436">
Link</a></li>
</ol>

<!--close button_small--> </div>
            <!--close content_container-->



<div id="content">
          <div class="content_item">
            
<h1> Student Poster/Presentation </h1>
<ol>

<br /><li>Fields, M., Deb, D., “Use of Machine Learning Methods for Vehicle Predictive Maintenance”, Oral presentation at 2020 NSF/AAAS Emerging Researchers National Conference (ERN) in STEM, February 2020. <a href= "content/FieldsERN2020.pdf">Abstract</a>
</br>

<br /><li>Rodrigues-Romero, D., Deb, D., “Stock Price Prediction using Ensemble Learning”, Poster presentation at 2020 NSF/AAAS Emerging Researchers National Conference (ERN) in STEM, February 2020. <a href= "content/DavidERN2020.pdf">Abstract</a>
</br>

<br /><li>Rodrigues-Romero, D., Deb, D., “Using Sentiment of News Articles to Predict Stock Price Performance”, Poster presentation at 2019 NSF/AAAS Emerging Researchers National Conference (ERN) in STEM, February 2019. <a href= "content/DavidERN2019.pdf">Poster (pdf)</a> 
</br>

<br /><li>Robert, J., Deb, D., “Data Science for Understanding and Assessing Spatial Justice”, Poster presentation at 2019 NSF/AAAS Emerging Researchers National Conference (ERN) in STEM, February 2019.<a href= "content/RobertERN2019.pdf">Poster (pdf)</a> 
</br>

<br /><li>Cousins, S., Deb, D., “Large-scale Workload Characterization in Apache Spark Framework”, Oral presentation at 2018 NSF/AAAS Emerging Researchers National Conference (ERN) in STEM, February 2018. <strong>(Awarded First Prize in the Undergraduate Computer Science Research Category)</strong>.<a href= "content/CousinsERN2018.pdf">Abstract</a>
</br>

<br /><li>Mathis, G., Cousins S., Deb D., “Music Mood Classification based on Lyrics”, Poster presentation at 2018 NSF/AAAS Emerging Researchers National Conference (ERN) in STEM, February 2018.<a <a href="content/George-ERN2018poster.pdf">Poster (pdf)</a></li>


<br /><li>Cousins, S., Deb, D., “Explore Spark-SQL and its performance using TPC-H Workload”, Poster presented at NC-LSAMP Annual Undergraduate Research Conference, NC state university, November 2017. <strong>(Awarded second prize in Computer Science research category)</strong>.<a href="content/Sebastian-NSLamps2018poster.pdf">Poster (pdf)</a></li>


<br /><li>Harp. N, Deb, D., “Sentiment Analysis of Tweets and Movie Reviews”. Poster presented at WSSU Scholarship day, April. 2017.<a href="content/NoelleAbstract.pdf">Abstract</a>, <a href="content/NoellePoster.pdf">Poster (pdf)</a></li>


<br /><li>Cousins, S., Deb, D., “Using Apache Spark in the Analysis of Wikipedia Page View Data in Correlation to the Real World Events”, Poster presented at WSSU Scholarship day, April. 2017<a href="content/SebastianAbstract.pdf">Abstract</a>, <a 
href="content/SebastianPoster.pdf">Poster (pdf)</a></li>

</ol>



            <div class="content_container"> </div>
            <!--close content_container-->
```

and here is the CSS

```
    #content
{ font: normal 100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 680px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 10px;
  float: left;
  }

.content_item
{ width: 680px;
  margin-top: .01px;
  margin-bottom: .01px;
margin-left: auto;
text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hava few issues:

1. first content div is not closed
2. you have several `</br>` instead of `</li>` (`br` tags dont need to be closed)
3. you are missing a `</div>` at the end

Here is a jsfiddle where everything works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2tbgf8qx/